# Which Desktop Environments have a Window Overview feature like Mac OS's Expose?

Tags: desktop-environments

I know that Unity (Super+W) and Gnome (Super) do have this feature. Are there any other DEs with a similiar feature? Or is there a software wich brings it to all DEs?

Answer (score 1):

`compiz` has an expose plugin (i think it's enabled by default, otherwise just activate it in compiz config settings manager). You can use it with any desktop environment you like (i use it with mate desktop for example).